# How to get started to write a driver for a keyboard backlight in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I would like to have some advice on how to get started with writing a Linux driver for the led on a keyboard.

I have an MSI Apache GE60 with the following keyboard:

[image]

Now, I know there **might** be already a driver for this, but I would like to take it as an educational challenge.

So the questions are:

1. How difficult is it for a CS with decent academic experience in C (writing web server, client, BST, Linked list)
2. What resources can I use to get this thing to show some color lights?

Any information that might be needed from me, just ask, I will add it as an edit.

Comment: How can I improve the question? Downvoter should at least advice on what he sees as wrong... That would make a better community.

Comment: Jumping from writing academic code for the things you list and writing a device driver for almost any operating system is a _huge_ jump. For that reason I think your question is far too broad.

Comment: It's not so much a huge difference in difficulty so much as a horizontal jump in skills. You'll find that you'll use close to nothing of your academic experience in Linux driver development and vice versa (not to say it won't be useful - it just won't be directly applicable). They're different fields altogether.

Comment: There's a good chance that the keyboard backlight is controlled through ACPI - so you'll want to read up on ACPI, install the ACPI debug tools and have a browse through the machine's decompiled DSDT.

Comment: Awesome, I think that is a pretty good answer. I'm not so sure where I'm getting into, but I would like to try, and if it is that different it is good at least to know about it. Note that my questions are basically easy to answer, I disagree with being too broad. I'm not asking what's the code, but more resources, and how difficult. Which's answered in comments.

Comment: Hi, did you go forward with the project? what were the dos dont dos? i'd like to take a dive myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't downvote but this question seems primarily opinion based.

As to your question, computer science theory will probably be largely irrelevant. Your biggest challenge will likely be writing "correct" Linux kernel code and learning how everything fits together. You'll want to read up all relevant notes and documentation in the kernel source code folder to ensure you're not doing stuff the wrong way.

In terms of resources, you can probably:

- Look up and hope there are data sheets describing the protocol/interface
- Look at existing drivers for similar hardware and see if you can adapt them instead
- Ask the manufacturer for documentation
- Reverse engineer any existing drivers for other operating systems

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the guidelines. I know the first question is totally opinion based, but resources are pretty straightforward. Anyhow, thanks for answering both.